# $X + Y \overset{\mathcal{D}}{=} X \Longrightarrow \mathbf{P}[Y = 0] =1$

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent, real random variables. Show that $X + Y \overset{\mathcal{D}}{=} X$ implies that $\mathbf{P}[Y = 0] =1$.
>
> *Note:* $U \overset{\mathcal{D}}{=} V$ means that the random variables $U$ and $V$ have the same distribution.

We know that a finite measure is fully determined by its characteristic function and vice versa.

Two random variables $U, V$ having the same distribution is equivalent to their pushforward measures $\mathbf{P}_U := \mathbf{P}\circ U^{-1}, \mathbf{P}_V$ being identical.

$$\phi_{\mathbf{P}_U}(t) = \int e^{i t x} \, d\mathbf{P}_U = \int e^{i t U} \, d\mathbf{P} =: \phi_U(t)$$

So $X + Y \overset{\mathcal{D}}{=} X$ is equivalent to $\phi_{X+Y} = \phi_{X}$.

Since $X, Y$ are independent, it must hold that $\phi_{X+Y} = \phi_X \phi_Y$, therefore
\begin{align*}
  \phi_X\phi_Y \overset{!}{=} \phi_X  \; \Rightarrow \; \phi_Y = 1 \; \Rightarrow \; 
   \int e^{i t Y }\, d \mathbf{P} = 1\,.
\end{align*}

One solution would be $Y = 0$ almost surely. But since a random variable is fully determined (almost surely) by its characteristic function, there cannot be another solution, so we conclude that $Y$ *must* be zero a. s. $\square$

***Is everything ok? Thank you!***

***NOTE: It is not assumed that $X$ and $Y$ have finite variance.***

Comment: You can't be sure that $\phi_X(t)\neq 0$ for all $t$ and therefore can't  divide by it for all $t$. However, we know that $\phi_X(t)\neq 0$ for $t\in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ (why?) and hence $\phi_Y(t)=1$ for $t\in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$. This is actually enough to conclude that $Y$ is constant almost surely.

Comment: Here's one idea: let $Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ be iid and independent of $X$.  Then $X + Y_1 + \dots + Y_n \overset{d}{=} X$.  So if $a_n \to 0$, we have $a_n(X + Y_1 + \dots + Y_n) \overset{d}{=} a_n X$.  We conclude that $a_n(X + Y_1 + \dots + Y_n) \to 0$ i.p., and hence also $a_n(Y_1 + \dots + Y_n) \to 0$ i.p.  If $a_n \to 0$ slowly (like $a_n = n^{-1/2}$ this implies that $Y_i = 0$ a.s., but I don't know of a direct way to see that, not even if $a_n = 1/\log n$ or something like that.  It can be shown using the central limit theorem but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1):

No, everything is not ok. You potentially divided by zero at a crucial step in your proof! In fact, the characteristic function of $X$ can vanish at certain $t$ values. For example, this happens when $X$ takes the values $0$ and $\pi$ with equal probability.

However, a modified argument can be used.

> Claim. Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables such that $X+Y$ and $X$ have the same distribution. Then $Y=0$ almost surely.

**Proof.**

Let $f(t)=\mathbb Ee^{itX}$, which is a continuous function of $t\in\mathbb R$. Since $f(0)=1$, applying continuity at $0$ yields an $\epsilon>0$ such that $|f(t)-1|<\tfrac12$ for all $|t|<\epsilon$. In particular, $|t|<\epsilon$ implies that $\mathbb Ee^{iXt}\not=0$.

By the hypotheses, we have that
$$
\mathbb Ee^{itX} \mathbb Ee^{itY}=\mathbb Ee^{itX},\qquad \forall t\in\mathbb R.
$$
When $|t|<\epsilon$, it follows that $\mathbb Ee^{itY}=1$. Taking real parts of both sides yields
$$
\mathbb E\cos(tY)=1,\qquad |t|<\epsilon.
$$
But this means that the non-negative random variable $1-\cos(tY)$ has mean zero, so that $1-\cos(tY)=0$ almost surely. Thus, $$Y\in \frac{2\pi}{t} \mathbb Z\text{ a.s.},\qquad \forall t\in (0,\epsilon).$$
Choosing $t_1,t_2\in (0,\epsilon)$ whose ratio is irrational leads to
$$
Y\in \frac{2\pi}{t_1} \mathbb Z\cap \frac{2\pi}{t_2} \mathbb Z=\{0\}\text{ a.s.},
$$
as desired.